# Ubuntu equivalent of Winforms?

Tags: application-development, programming

I am someone who has spent maybe 2 or 3 years developing business applications using C# and Winforms.

At home I would like to learn how to do the equivalent in Ubuntu. What language should I be using? What API does Ubuntu use for showing forms?

Are there any nice 'drag and drop'  editors that I can make use of for making forms as quickly as I can in Windows?

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3693656/alternative-to-winforms-that-can-be-easily-used-with-c-sharp-and-net